# Windows 8.1 dfrgui not seeing drive C or not starting at all

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-8.1, defragment

I've made a clean re-install of Windows 8.1 x64 today. I decided to check the disk defragmentation schedule. To my surprise, `dfrgui.exe` did not list drive `C:`, showing only my external hard drive (drive `D:`). It shows this:

[image]

Funny thing is, if I plug the external HDD out, `dfrgui` doesn't start. At all.

I've seen a similar issue discussed [here](http://www.eightforums.com/performance-maintenance/49666-windows-8-basic-defrag-tool-wont-open.html), however, in that case, the asker's problem was resolved by repairing some corrupted files, which `SFC /SCANNOW` doesn't find on my computer.

What could be the problem with `dfrgui`? And what can I do to fix it?

Comment: have you tried some other program that does the samething as this tool?

Comment: Is your C drive an SSD or a spinning hard drive?

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton: regular HDD, not an SSD.

Comment: @Ramhound: no, not yet... can you recommend any good ones?

Comment: @Mints97 - No;  There are hundreds of tools; You should pick one yourself.